# Is there a specific term for horizontal gutters?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, terminology, white-space

**Context**
My team is working on a responsive website and we allow the user to configure some of the properties of the page, including the spaces between the grid "cells". We had a conversation about the correct terminology to identify the "space between cells". Obviously we could use something like "margin", but that's a bit too broad as that would include the space between the page and the outermost cells. We want to identify the space between cells only. Our users are not necessarily tech-savvy (meaning CSS, etc), but may have some background in graphic design (or at least be familiar with common terminology).

**The Question**
"Gutter" seems like the most correct term, but most of the definitions for "gutter" that I can find specifically refer to the space between *columns*.

Is there a specific term for the space between *rows*? Or is it appropriate to simply refer to them as "horizontal gutters"?

**Example**
Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to identify.
(Image borrowed from https://www.init.de/en/news/responsive-design)

[image]

**Issues with My Current Terminology**
"Horizontal(/Vertical) Gutter" is a bit confusing, in my opinion, as it's unclear whether the gutter is between horizontal(/vertical) elements or if it provides horizontal(/vertical) space between vertical(/horizontal) elements. There's some disagreement on my team about which definition is accurate, so I think that's evidence enough that the phrase is actually confusing.

At least in relation to the web, "padding" and "margin" aren't appropriate for what I'm describing. Padding refers to the space between the border and the content, while margin refers to the space *around* an element. Two adjacent elements with a margin of 10px each would have a 20px gutter between them. (Yes, I'm aware that CSS margins often collapse, [but not always](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#item-margins).)

I've seen the term "gutter" used often in responsive grid frameworks, so I know it's an acceptable term in web development. I'm just wondering if there is a more appropriate term for a "horizontal gutter".

Comment: Good question, I don't know of a term for it. However, the term gutter is often misused. The spacing between columns is properly called an *alley*. [See this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bAsM8.gif) for clarification

Comment: You specifically don't mean leading here, do you? What about paragraph spacing?

Comment: Context is everything. As this sounds like a table, I'd suggest borrowing whatever terminology MS Excel uses when choosing formatting options for spreadsheet cells (I think it's 'padding' IIRC)

Comment: As for *paragraph spacing* if we're talking truly about the horizontal space between paragraphs in a column I believe the term graphic designers use *is* 'paragraph spacing'.

Comment: Cell spacing is not correct, as that adds space around the outside of the table/grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

I would use "row spacing".

**Long answer**

As JDB mentioned, I too would rather use web-related terms as opposed to trying to import typesetting terms from the (fascinating) printed media world.

I would use the terms "column spacing" and "row spacing" because most grid layouts use the terms "column" and "grid". I would avoid using the terms "margin" and "padding" to avoid clashes with CSS keywords.

Comment: The new CSS Grid spec defines [`grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap), but I actually like "spacing" just a little bit better.

Answer (score 7):

In the scope of web design, which seems to be the scope of the OP's question, I would rather use web-related terms as opposed to trying to import typesetting terms from the (fascinating) printed media world.

I would call this "vertical margin" as in the CSS margin property. The margin is the spacing between the border of adjacent elements (as opposed to the padding, which is the spacing inside the element, between its border and its content.)

[image]

In W3C's words:

> The margin clears an area around an element (outside the border). The margin does not have a background color, and is completely transparent.
>   [source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Please notice that the border of the element can be transparent. It does not need to be visible.

Developers are bound to understand this term quite clearly. And, in my opinion, albeit "margin" is less charming than "gutter", "aisle" or "slug", clients are bound to find it a friendlier term.

**Digression**

`Cellpadding` and `cellspacing` are similar to `padding` and `margin`, but they are too specific. They are  valid html attributes of the `<table>` and `<td>` tags as opposed to general CSS attributes. They cannot be applied to any other tag but those. If you are talking only about tables (as in constructs made using the `<table>` tag) then you would be correct if you call that area `cellspacing`.  If you are talking about rectangular areas in general (as in areas defined by `<div>`, `<span>`, `<img>` or any other tag), then `margin` would be more accurate.

Just as a side comment, please notice that the `cellpading` and `cellspacing` attributes are highly frown upon modern web designers and developers because this type of attribute mixes up structure (HTML) with style (CSS) resulting in pages that are harder to maintain and/or develop by teams. Developers are encouraged to refrain from using these attributes and use the CSS attributes `padding` and `margin` instead.

Same thing applies to using tables to create general layouts, as it used to be. Purists claim that tables should be used only to display tabular data. `<div>` and `<span>` tags should be used for scaffolding. All this hoping that one day we will have semantically correct webpages were the tags mark up the context semantically as opposed to be backstage rigging only.

Comment: "Margin" is a general term referring to the space *around* elements, whereas "gutter" specifically refers to the space *between* elements. For example, if two contiguous elements each have a margin of 10px, then the gutter between them would be 20px wide. I've seen "gutter" used often in various grid layout frameworks, so I don't think it's out of bounds in the context of websites. I'm just wondering if that's the correct term for the space between vertically stacked elements.

Comment: @JDB: Fair enough... I guess the acceptance of "gutter" as the space between elements would depend on your audience. BTW, in HTML/CSS margins sometimes collapse together so two elements with 10px margin not necessarily would have a 20px gutter. They might end up with a 10px gutter if the margins collapse. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/

Comment: Also, (not being annoying, I am just very enthusiastic about this theme) in CSS "margin" is not a general term. It has a very specific definition. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: That's true, but not always. For example, the flexbox specification specifically says that [margins of adjacent flex items do not collapse](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#item-margins).

Comment: Good point. I agree it would be better to have a term that refers to "the actual space that is finally left between the elements".

Comment: Even though they list all of the ways margins will *not* collapse," margin collapse seems to be the exception rather than the rule in the documentation. At least, the documentation reads like English grammar books: no rule and all exceptions. Perhaps, at least for your team, you define a term (like "alley") which is the vertical margin between elements after (non-)collapse.

Comment: @Yorik: Agreed that margin collapsing is one of the most unpredictable and annoying quirks of CSS.

Comment: If you call it a "margin" how do you distinguish between the external margins and the margins of adjacent elements? Surely this is where using "margin" and "gutter" work better because at least then you can distinguish between the two.

Comment: I agree that gutter would be a nice term, but if the OP was looking for a word that ties directly to CSS (not clear if he is) there is no such thing as gutter - only margins and padding.

Answer (score 4):

In typesetting terms, **[Slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28typesetting%29)** is a common term for a horizontal gap. - Space after/before a paragraph, a horizontal gap between sections, or between rules, etc. The slug has a specified size similar to type sizes and would be placed inline with the metal type to create the proper vertical spacing.

### based upon the edit....

`Cell padding` seems the most obvious choice. Or `cell spacing`.

Comment: Does this term apply to spacing after sections as well? or just paragraphs?

Comment: I like it, but it's very confusing in web design since there's a second definition at play.

Comment: Context is always key :) In addition to *who* you are speaking to.

Comment: Sorry @Scott, wasn't aware what pieces of context would be most relevant for the question.

Comment: I think 'slug' in this context predates most graphic designers working today. Even the older of us would use the definition of a line of set type via a linotype machine. As such, I wouldn't use this term in the web site UI as it wouldn't be a recognizable term to most.

Comment: @scott actually, 'hot type' can often refer to multiple things as well. I *think* (but am not certain) most graphic designers, when they hear 'hot top' are thinking of the linotype era where the slugs were the actual lines of type--not the space between paragraphs. The slug would INCLUDE letterspacing, but not necessarily paragraph spacing (granted, most places using linotypes didn't actually *have* paragraph spacing as they were typically newspapers).

Comment: ... and realize the question was edited to add much more after I posted this answer. There was no real mention of "web" previously.

Comment: Love the term, slug (+1). I am so using it now every chance I have.

Answer (score 2):

In layout design those horizontal gutters in a grid are called “flow lines” or “hang lines”

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Please explain your answer better. What do you mean with "layout design"?

Comment: To add to what Kurt said, maybe you can include visual examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been teaching typography for 40+ years and I have your complete answer. The person who suggested **flow lines** is correct. To my knowledge, this term is post modern, not from classic typography. The first defined graphic modular grids were derived from observing Le Corbusier's architectural drawings. (By two unnamed Swiss graphic designers.)(Apparently)

In print typography when creating a modular grid, the modules are based on the vertical and horizontal typographic measurements of the typeface chosen. The vertical column is determined by numbers of text lines deep. The width of the modules is determined by the number of characters wide in each module.If I choose 12 point Helvetica regular on and 18 point line space or 12/18 pts, all horizontal lines will be a measure of 18 points. If you leave a space between paragraphs, most designers will leave one line space between paragraphs if they aren't indenting the first line of each paragraph.

That blank space is called **line space** or 18 point line spaces.

When creating a modular grid, one made up of defined equal blocks... say 3 column modules wide by 6 modules deep or 18 modules in total. Each module might represent 6 lines of text. The vertical spaces between the columns are called **gutters**, and the 5 horizontal lines separating the 6 modules are called **flow lines, flow, horizon lines, horizons or 5 full line spaces**. These all depend on the typographic language one is taught to use, but they will all mean the same thing.

If a modular grid is not made up of equal modules and the pattern irregular, your random horizontal spaces between modules will still be called flow lines or horizons. This occurs when your type sizes vary. You might be using 12/18 points in several modules and 9/13 points in other modules.

A typographic book that demonstrates modular formations is **THE GRID** by **Alan Hurlburt**. Unfortunately the explanations are vague at best, however if one is visually astute and can grasp visual content, you can figure out how the patterns were arrived at.